# Gridview Disappearing jQuery ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm creating a web application that will allow editing of a database table using ASP.NET.

I've got all the functionality in the application, and everything is working fine. However, now the specification has changed and I need to have multiple gridview's showing different database tables. So, I've implemented jquery and a dropdown menu that'll only show certain div's depending on the value chosen in the dropdown menu.

This is well, I only display the gridview I want to depending on the value I have chosen. Although, when trying to edit the gridview, the gridview disappears; this only happens since implementing the jquery.

I can display the gridview again when I choose a different option in the dropdown menu and then choose the option I want.

This is stange because the edit button should not effect the value I have chosen on a drop down menu.

Could anyone help please?

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.group').hide();
            $('#no_option_selected').show();
            $('#DropDownList1').change(function () {
                $('.group').hide();
                $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
            })
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Every time you edit one of your gridviews, your entire page. And every time your page reloads, your jQuery hides all the tables. Store the selected grid view in a cookie in  you javascript. Or put the show / hide logic in your codebehind page in c#.

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder would this also work if I used an iframe on the Default page, and the iframe only shows seperate pages? The only thing I don't like about this is having different pages for every table.

Comment: I probably would not use iframes in this case.

Comment: you have assign class group to every ddl and hence the effect. check what is coming in alert($(this).val()), is the ID coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe easier to do everything in .NET / C#, rather than ASP.NET / jQuery hybrid. Turn your dropdownlist into a server control and define a OnSelectedIndexChanged. (Don't forget to set Autopostback to True)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    OnSelectedIndexchanged="Gridview_ShowHide">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And then in your code behind:

```
public void Gridview_ShowHide(Object o, EventArgs e) 
{
    gv1.Visible = gv2.Visible = gv3.Visible = gv4.Visible = false;
    switch (DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    {
         case 'gv1':
              gv1.Visible = True;
              break;
         case 'gv2':
              gv2.Visible = True;
              break;
         case 'gv3':
              gv3.Visible = True
              break;
         case 'gv4':
              gv4.Visible = True;
              break;
    }
}
```

By doing this, ASP.NET's ViewState will keep track of which gridview is visible and not visible, even after postback.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Once back in the office, I'll give this method  a try. It seems more maintainable than my iframe and multiple different web form solution.